# What's the best way to get transactions for an address using web3.py?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

I'm trying to write a script that will use a public Ethereum address and get a list of all the transaction hashes.  I'm using [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) but the methods I see for getting transaction information use the transaction hash as an input.  I'm trying to get a list of hashes for a given address.  Do I need to search through each block to see if the address in every single hash?  I thought there'd be some simple way to get all the transactions in a single method.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: this question was answered many times

Comment: @Nulik great!  Can you tell me where?

Comment: `geth` doesn't provide such RPC request because building index of address->transactions is compute intense and database hungry. the database is large enough so no "good to have" features are included.

Comment: Thank you. So do I have to search every transaction of every block to get all the transactions for an address?

Comment: correct .. . . .